# Typescript: Define function as a const

Tags: typescript

I follow the Typescript handbook for [decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) and the signature is written as

```
function reportableClassDecorator<T extends { new (...args: any[]): {} }>(constructor: T) {
```

Writing like this the compiler complains that I shouldn't use `function` and `const` are preferable.

I tried as well a reduced form

```
export const reportableClassDecorator = (constructor: Function)  => {
```

but here the compiler complains that I should use `Function` as a type.

Therefore: How to define it properly (for the compiler)?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use the `Function` type here, just write the same function as an arrow function. With an arrow function, type parameters come before the opening `(` of the parameter list:

```tyepscript
const reportableClassDecorator = <T extends { new (...args: any[]): {} }>(
    constructor: T
) => {
    // ...implementation
};
```

If you wanted an explicit return type, it comes after the closing `)` on the parameter list, before the `=>`.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUwA4jlAhgIwDYIMLboQQAiCoc6UqMAvDADwAqMCAHlAmACYQwDeMMAgDuMABQA6aejgBzCAC4Y6MAE8A2gF0AlMv4BfGAYB840JChwArsGpxlTHXRMCDAbiA)

More details on writing function types and function expressions in [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions).

Comment: If I do it like this than the compiler (or eslint?) complains about the `new (...args: any[]): {}` part: `Type literal only has a call signature, you should use a function type instead|Unexcpeted any. Specify a different type.@Don's use {} as ...`

Comment: @LeO - That's a different issue. The above is an accurate translation of your `function` declaration. If you need to add a further signature, you can do that, but I can't guess at what you're looking for without more information in the question.

Comment: ahhh... I understand... Basically I was thinking that after transforming it into a `const`  eslint (from Angular) would stop annoying me the request to define the `function` as `const`. Honestly I didn't expect that eslint would come with another issue. Bottom line: I want to have a declaration which satisfy `eslint`